# Postgres Analyze performed

Tags: postgresql, analyzer

In PostgreSQL 8.4, is there a way to know when the last ANALYZE and/or VACUUM has been performed on a table?

I've been looking around in the documentation and later the pg_catalog but not been able to find anything useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That would be pg_stat_all_tables

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/monitoring-stats.html

Comment: Thanks, missed the attributes on that table.

Answer (score 0):

In PgAdminIII (I just assume that this is the tool of choice since it is great ;)), you see these information in the statistics column. There are entries for analyze/vauum and autoanalyze/autovacuum respectively.